# extra unwanted TextView appear in GridView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gridview

i have a GridView with only a picture in the Row layout
but i keep getting this unwanted TextView with "title" text within it

i searched the row xml file over and all the code but i can't find where is this TextView come from

**fragment_category_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp">
    <TextView style="@style/WizardPageTitle" />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridCategoryList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:columnWidth="125dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/grid_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

category_row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ededed">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cat_cars" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_category

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_layout, container, false);
        txtTitle = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.title));
        txtTitle.setText(mPage.getTitle());
        final int[] icons = new int[mChoices.size()];//mChoices.toArray(]);
        for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++)
            icons[i] = Integer.valueOf(mChoices.get(i));

        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridCategoryList);
        gridView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), icons));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (previousSelectedView != null) previousSelectedView.setSelected(false);
                v.setSelected(true);
                previousSelectedView = v;
                mPage.getData().putString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY,
                        String.valueOf(icons[position]));
                wizSession.setValue(pageKey, String.valueOf(position + 1));

                //wizSession.setValue(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY, String.valueOf(position + 1));
                //mPage.getData().putString(Page.SIMPLE_DATA_KEY, String.valueOf(position + 1));
                mPage.notifyDataChanged();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Category_adapter

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int[] mCategoryImg;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, int[] imageItems) {

        this.mCategoryImg = imageItems;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCategoryImg.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mCategoryImg[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_row, null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoryImage);
        imageView.setImageResource(mCategoryImg[i]);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

a picture to sample what i mean
[highlighted with red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOjGZ.png)

Comment: Its not possible do you calling wrong xml

Comment: i searched the code over and over, i can't find if it's calling another xml but am pretty sure it's call the above xml which don't have title text

Comment: Create new row XML . Don't copy paste  definitely your problem get resolved

Comment: problem get resolved .?

Comment: The problem resolved, what was causing the problem that I have included a library which has the same layout name (category_item.xml), I just did refractory to rename the layout and it's solved :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved, what was causing the problem that I have included a library which has the same layout name (category_item.xml), I just did refractory to rename the layout and it's solved :D